# How do you solve $EllipticE [0.5,-600]$ analytically with series expansion method?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, elliptic-curves, elliptic-integrals

How do you solve $EllipticE [0.5,-600]$ analytically with series expansion method?

I suspect a modulus transformation should be used inorder to set $0 <k <1$ where k is -600 in the example.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+EllipticE%5B1%2F2%2C-k%5D+around+k%3Dinfinity

Answer (score 1):

When $k$ is large, using Wolfram notation, and for for more simplicity letting $t=\frac 1{ \sqrt{k}}$ and consider
$$E\left(\left.\frac{1}{2}\right|-k\right)= E\left(\frac{1}{2}|-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)$$ a series expansion is
$$\frac{2 \sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{t}+\frac{1}{4} t \left(-2 \log \left(t
   \left(2+\sqrt{2 (1+\cos (1))}\right)\right)+1+\log (64)+2 \log \left(\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right)+$$ $$\frac{1}{64} t^3 \left(4 \log
   \left(\frac{1}{4} t \left(2+\sqrt{2 (1+\cos (1))}\right)\right)+3-2 \log (2-2
   \cos (1))+2 \sqrt{2 (1+\cos (1))} \csc
   ^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+O\left(t^5\right)$$

Truncated to these terms, for $k=600$, this would give $3.074528758$ while the "exact" value would be                                 $3.074534459$.

Computing the coefficients and making them rational would give
$$\frac{237}{1936 t}+\frac{1}{4} t \left(\frac{2416}{655}-2 \log \left(\frac{15813
   }{4211}t\right)\right)+\frac{1}{64} t^3 \left(4 \log \left(\frac{3635
   }{3872}t\right)+\frac{50914}{2761}\right)+O\left(t^5\right)$$

For the more general case, have a look [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE2/06/01/13/).

Comment: Hello. Thanks for this great answer. Now here phi is unkown so how do ı take the inverse of this? So if we say X=EllipticE(phi,-k) then what is phi interms of X and k?